# Como puedo agregarle la fecha a una url de imagen?

Tags: javascript, html, img

tengo una duda,

tengo esta imagen
img src="https://es.tideschart.com/tides/es/horarios-de-mareas-Rada-Tilly-Argentina-m.png?date="

donde ?date= deberia ser ?date=20200725 <---- fecha actual.

como puedo agregarle la fecha actual al final de ese tag img?
la idea es que me traiga todos los dias la tabla de mareas correspondiente a ese dia.

trate con esto que me da el formato que necesito pero no se como ponerselo al tag img y que me traiga la imagen del dia.

```
<script>
 var f = new Date();
 document.write(f.getFullYear());
 document.write(f.getMonth()+1);
 document.write(f.getDate());
</script>
```

gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código:

```html
<img id="mareas-img">
```

```
const fechaActual = new Date()

const escribirFecha = (fecha) => {
  return `${fecha.getFullYear()}${fecha.getMonth()+1}${fecha.getDate()}`
}

let fechaTxt = escribirFecha(fechaActual)

const img = document.getElementById("mareas-img")
img.src = `https://es.tideschart.com/tides/es/horarios-de-mareas-Rada-Tilly-Argentina-m.png?date=${fechaTxt}`
```

Lo que hace este código es:

- Obtener la fecha actual en `fechaActual`
- Crea una función `escribirFecha` que coloca el día, mes y año en una cadena de texto
- En `fechaTxt` se almacena la fecha de hoy `20200725`
- Le asigna el atributo `src` a la imagen `#mareas-img`

PD: Recuerda colocar el script al final del body