# HTML, Cambiar la fecha en <img src

Tags: html, date, img, src, autocomplete

Hola no soy programador soy tecnico de audiovisuales y necesito ayuda de un profesional de html
tengo este archivo html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>template</title>
<style type="text/css">
.margen { 
width:1920 px;
height: 1080 px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top: 0px;
</style></head>
<body class="margen">
<div>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2000">
<img src="https://img.kiosko.net/2022/09/11/es/mundodeportivo.750.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que hace es mostrarme una portada de un periodico. Necesito poder cambiar la fecha de: https://img.kiosko.net/2022/09/11/es/mundodeportivo.750.jpg
[image]
Necesito que cada dia cuando ejecute el html me muestre la portada de ese dia.
Para ello necesito que se modifique automaticamente la fecha.

img.kiosko.net/FECHA_ACTUAL/es/mundodeportivo.750.jpg

Despues de investigar lo que he podido por la web lo mas parecido a lo que quiero creo q se explica aqui:
[Como puedo agregarle la fecha a una url de imagen?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376207/como-puedo-agregarle-la-fecha-a-una-url-de-imagen)
de ahi he creado un html pero no me funciona he puesto el script antes del body

El html que no me funciona es este:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>template</title>
<style type="text/css">
.margen { 
width:1920 px;
height: 1080 px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top: 0px;
</style></head>
<body class="margen">
<script>
 var f = new Date();
 document.write(f.getFullYear()+1);
 document.write(f.getMonth()+1);
 document.write(f.getDate()+1);
</script
<div>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2000">
<img src="https://img.kiosko.net/new Date()/es/mundodeportivo.750.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html
```

Gracias por vuestra atencion

Despues de las indicaciones de Mauricio el html quedaria asi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>template</title>
<style type="text/css">
.margen { 
width:1920 px;
height: 1080 px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top: 0px;
</style></head>
<body class="margen">
<div>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2000">
<img id="mundo_deportivo" src="https://img.kiosko.net/${fecha.getUTCFullYear()}/${month}/${day}/es/mundodeportivo.750.jpg">
</div>
<script>
const imagen = document.getElementById('mundo_deportivo');
const fecha = new Date();
const month = (fecha.getUTCMonth() + 1) .toString().padStart(2, '0');
const day = fecha.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const url = `https://img.kiosko.net/${fecha.getUTCFullYear()}/${month}/${day}/es/mundodeportivo.750.jpg`;
imagen.src = url;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

SOLUCIONADO

Comment: Y cómo lo has intentado? Puedes explicar un poco más eso que has intentado? Saludos

Comment: Despues de investigar lo que he podido por la web lo mas parecido a lo que quiero creo q se explica aqui:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376207/como-puedo-agregarle-la-fecha-a-una-url-de-imagen de ahi he creado un html pero no me funciona
he puesto el script antes del body

Comment: El html que  he hecho es este:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>template</title>
<style type="text/css">
.margen { 
width:1920 px;
height: 1080 px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top: 0px;
</style></head>
<script>
 var f = new Date();
 document.write(f.getFullYear());
 document.write(f.getMonth()+1);
 document.write(f.getDate());
</script>
<body class="margen">
<div>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2000">
<img src="https://img.kiosko.net/new Date/es/mundodeportivo.750.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Veo que recargas la página con un etiqueta `meta`. Puedes obtener la fecha actual con `JavScript`. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181354/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-una-fecha-en-formato-dd-mm-yyyy-con-javascript) y le das el formato que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es simple, sólo debes darle un atributo `id` a tu elemento de imagen y mediante [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) puedes asignar el valor del atributo `src` a ese elemento de imagen. Por ejemplo:

```html
<img id="mundo_deportivo" src="">
```

Luego, al final del documento, justo antes del cierre de la etiqueta `body` insertas tu script que se encargará de establecer el valor `src` a tu imagen, de la siguiente forma:

```html
<script>
const imagen = document.getElementById('mundo_deportivo');
const fecha = new Date();
const month = (fecha.getUTCMonth() + 1) .toString().padStart(2, '0');
const day = fecha.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const url = `https://img.kiosko.net/${fecha.getUTCFullYear()}/${month}/${day}/es/mundodeportivo.750.jpg`;
imagen.src = url;
</script>
```

He utilizado los métodos [`getUTC*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate) para obtener el año, el mes y el dia sin importar la zona horaria del cliente. También he usado el método [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) para añadir un cero en caso que el mes o el día sean menores que 10.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

```html
<img id="mundo_deportivo" src="">
<script>
const imagen = document.getElementById('mundo_deportivo');
const fecha = new Date();
const month = (fecha.getUTCMonth() + 1) .toString().padStart(2, '0');
const day = fecha.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const url = `https://img.kiosko.net/${fecha.getUTCFullYear()}/${month}/${day}/es/mundodeportivo.750.jpg`;
imagen.src = url;
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Mauricio lo he provado y funciona perfectamente se abre la portada solo hay un problema me muestra la portada del mes anterior es decir la fecha que introduce es 2022/08/11 en vez de 2022/09/11

Comment: Este es el html que he hecho

Comment: <img id="elperiodico_cat" src="https://img.kiosko.net/${fecha.getUTCFullYear()}/${month}/${day}/es/elperiodico_cat.750.jpg">
</div>
<script>
const imagen = document.getElementById('elperiodico_cat');
const fecha = new Date();
const month = fecha.getUTCMonth().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const day = fecha.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const url = `https://img.kiosko.net/${fecha.getUTCFullYear()}/${month}/${day}/es/elperiodico_cat.750.jpg`;
imagen.src = url;
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que me de la fecha correcta

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboracion

Comment: @Manolo he editado mi respuesta. Olvidé que `getUTCMonth` y `getMonth` devuelven el valor del mes empezando desde 0, siendo 0 correspondiente a Enero y 11 correspondiente a Diciembre. Por lo cual al valor devuelto por `getUTCMonth` hay que sumarle 1 antes de convertirlo a cadena. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto ahora funciona muchas gracias por ayudarme con tus conocimientos un saludo cordial